# Как сделать живой поиск если json по очень большой (35MB)

Tags: redux, create-react-app, semantic-ui

Делаю на reacte + redux + semantic-ui живой поиск для input при вводе текста.
Куда засунуть json чтобы живой поиск работал быстро?
json размером около 35MB.

Answer (score 0):

35 мегабайт - это не так уж много и вряд ли проблема в поиске (ну если ты не совсем накосячил в нём). Проверь, что ты не пытаешься отобразить сразу все данные на странице (используй виртуализацию) и всякая возня со сторами написана достаточно оптимально.

Сниппет при запуске может зависнуть на несколько секунд - просто генерируются данные.

```js
function measure(msg, f) {
  var start = performance.now()
  var res = f()
  console.log(msg, (performance.now() - start).toFixed(3) + " ms")
  return res
}

var data = measure(
  "Generate 35 MB of data (not optimized)",
  () => Array(350000).fill().map(() => Array(105).fill().map(() => String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt(0) + ~~(Math.random() * 26))).join(""))
)

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', event => {
  var text = event.target.value.toLowerCase()
  var res

  measure(
    `Search for "${text}":`,
    () => res = data.filter(s => s.includes(text))
  )
  
  document.querySelector('output').textContent = `Found ${res.length} records`;
})
```

```html
<input> <output></output>
```

На моём компьютере фильтрация происходит быстрее чем за 100 миллисекунд. Не так чтоб прям мгновенно, но вполне приемлемо, если искать не при вводе (как у меня), а с некоторой паузой. Да и данных я нагенерировал больше - тут 36 750 000 символов, а у json'а есть накладные расходы на имена ключей, кавычки и кириллица в UTF8 занимает по 2 байта, а не по одному; наверняка у тебя не только текст, а какие-нибудь id есть, в общем, при 35 МБ json'а данных будет меньше.

[image: скриншот]